# Javascript: What happens to the old object when I create a new instance?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm not even sure how to phrase this question so I'll have to go with examples. This might not look like useful code here, and indeed it isn't, but it's an example of a problem I've just encountered, stripped down to the bare essentials.

Lets' assume I have

```
function myObject(params) {

    .. do some time-consuming asynchronous stuff 
       with AJAX and the like ...

    return (before all the above is completed);

}

function myFunction(params) {

    var doTheSlowStuff = new myObject(params);

}

myFunction(firstParams);
myFunction(moreParams);
```

What happens to the first myObject when I make the second call to myFunction()? Does it get a chance to complete its work (and if so will it be garbage collected when it has)? Or does it get unceremoniously dumped before it has a chance to finish what it started?

Comment: Both calls to `myObject` will complete (i.e., the async behavior will indeed occur twice). I don't think you've included enough information in this example to say for sure whether any information will be lost, but it's quite possible. Each invocation of `myFunction` creates its own `doTheSlowStuff` variable, so future calls will not destroy the `doTheSlowStuff` from another call. However, if that value leaves the scope of `myFunction`, all bets are off and clobbering can indeed occur.

Comment: You could return a promise from `myObject` and handle success in `myFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

All the time-consuming asynchronous stuff will happen asynchronously :)

That means that the async calls (such as XHR or setTimeout) return instantly and allow execution to continue. In other words, the myObject constructor will return very quickly so there will be no delay between constructing the two myObjects. After *both* myFunctions return, then finally control will return to the event loop and the JavaScript engine will continue processing events, like mouse clicks, WebSocket events, timers like setTimeout, or XHR requests coming back. Your asynchronous callbacks won't be executed until you return control to the event loop, so don't do anything crazy like

```
while(true) {
    // Check XHR status
}
```

Don't worry about garbage collection; if you have a DOM event like an AJAX (XHR) request with  your myObject in scope then it won't be garbage collected until the event handler itself is garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific instance, you will create two instances of `myObject` which will be retained in memory until your application exits.

You can prove this by running something asynchronously to test this behaviour:

```
function myObject(params) {

  // do something async, like output
  // every second ...
  var callback = function () {
    console.log("I am object " + params);
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
  };
  callback (); 

}

function myFunction(params) {

    var doTheSlowStuff = new myObject(params);

}

myFunction(1);
myFunction(2);
// etc.
```

See a working example at: http://jsbin.com/osEFuWib/1/edit

Comment: 'until your application exits'

That's interesting. You've allowed me to shed some more light on my question. What I want myObject to do is to iterate over an array of params, calling either AJAX functions or some other functions that return a promise on each vaule in the array. I don't care about a return value from myFunction or myObject. What I want to avoid is what you seem to suggest will happen - that every myObject I create will remain in memory even when all the aysnchronous stuff has finished. Is this is the case? If so I'll have to find some other method.

Comment: @MarkGreenwood The bottom line is that if you don't have any references to your data, it will be garbage collected eventually. So there's no particular reason why you *can't* use JavaScript for your memory-hungry app. It might not be the most appropriate tool for this use case, and you might have to be careful to ensure that you really don't have any leaks, but you can use JavaScript. Just make super sure that no closure with your data in scope is reachable from anywhere in the DOM, including event handlers attached to DOM elements, or anything in global scope. Watch that video I linked above.

Comment: @Brian Gordon Thanks, I think that's what I needed to know. It's not a memory hungry app (yet) and this question was about me trying to prevent it from becoming so - I didn't phrase it all that well.

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous code has access to a *callback function*. The callback *will run* and is *independent* of any other object. "Losing" the object or creating a new object does not change this. As such, pending asynchronous operations must be explicitly cancelled or the callbacks must be guarded against performing unwanted effects when they are invoked.

The thing about objects in JavaScript is simple: as long as *any code* - including the callback - can access the object (e.g. assigned to a variable in scope, a window property, or bound to the DOM), they remain accessible. Otherwise, they are *unreachable* and will be reclaimed at some point.

Comment: One thing to add: the DOM can also reference objects and prevent them from being garbage collected. Here's an excellent talk on how you can uncover these leaks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9Jlu_h_Lyw

Comment: @BrianGordon Good point. I consider that just accessible from code, but note added.